# Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 31 is not installed

Tags: jar

I am getting the following error in a Xamarin Forms application. I have migrated my application to AndroidX.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 31 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android

Comment: I'm getting this same error, but only when running MSBuild in command line. i.e. works fine in Visual Studio, just not in command line. API 31 is definitely installed.

Comment: @kashif, take a look in this thread/issue:[10222](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10222)